# Medir longitud del texto a cada elemento de una misma clase y asignar función si cumple condición

Tags: javascript, html

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
<p class="text">texto longitud correcta</p>
    <p class="text">texto largo longitud xxxxxxxxx </p>


    [...document.getElementsByClassName("text")].forEach(function(e){
    e.innerHTML = e.innerHTML.replace(/(.{1,23})(.*)/g, "$1...");
    })
```

Obtengo lo siguiente:

texto longitud correcta...

texto largo longitud xx...

La función actúa, pero afecta también al texto con longitud correcta

Como puedo medir la longitud del texto a cada elemento de una misma clase y asignar función si cumple condición?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prueba mejor con esta expresión regular:

```
/^(.{1}.{23})(.*)/g
```

### Explicación

Primer grupo capturado: `(.{1}.{23})`

- `.` : encuentra cualquier caracter (excepto los terminadores de línea)
- `{1}` : encuentra el caracter previo tan solo una vez
- `.` : encuentra cualquier caracter (excepto los terminadores de línea)
- `{23}` : encuentra el caracter previo 23 veces

Segundo grupo capturado: `(.*)`

- `.` : encuentra cualquier caracter (excepto los terminadores de línea)
- `*` : encuentra el caracter previo entre 0 y infinitas veces, tantas veces como es posible

Ejemplo:

```js
[...document.getElementsByClassName("text")].forEach(function(e) {
  e.innerHTML = e.innerHTML.replace(/^(.{1}.{23})(.*)/g, "$1...");
})
```

```html
<p class="text">texto longitud correcta</p>
<p class="text">texto largo longitud xxxxxxxxx </p>
```

Comment: estoy viendo tantas respuestas con expresiones regulares que me siento en la obligacion de aprenderlas, parecen muy utiles

Comment: Truco para entenderlas y probarlas: `https://regex101.com/`

Comment: Funcionó perfectamente. Gracias